# Heap distribution among processes on single box?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have 10 GB of heap on server.  I have two process running on that on linux box(64 bit JVM 8)

Process 1 :- -Xms 512M  -Xmx 8192M. Say right now its using only 4G(4096M)

Now i want to start another process(Process 2) with -Xms 512M  -Xmx 3072M.

Will process 2 able to start ? As it want to reserve 3G memory but  process 1 has already reserved 8G memory or reserved memory by process 1 does not matter as actually its using only 4G at this point of time

Comment: *"Will process 2 able to start ?"* ... have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried it. It does not start. But I want to understand that is this behavior correct and also the theory also behind it

Comment: do you have swap? what's the [overcommit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) sysctl?